# dockerとrailsで環境構築をしようとしているのだがうまく行かない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。
参考にしたサイトはこちらです。

[DockerでRuby on Railsの開発環境を構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/chisaki0606/items/a4b42af5c4735c94057a)

こちらの画像で出てくるように、yay!youre on rails　の画面にいけません。
どうしたら良いでしょうか。

dockerをアンインストールしてもう一回入れてもだめでした。

Answer (score 0):

[丁寧すぎるDocker-composeによるrails5 + MySQL on Dockerの環境構築(Docker for Mac) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/azul915/items/5b7063cbc80192343fc0)

上記の記事を参考にしたらできました。
おそらくこちらで使われているPostgreSQLと私が使おうとしたMySQLとぶつかってしまっていたみたいです。